# Return one Element from List using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a list that contains 3 variables, expense, salary and year. I would like to return all expenses from the list using LINQ. Writing a foreach loop would suffice but I was hoping to archive something more efficient using LINQ.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
List<Company> ListCompanies = new List<Company>();

Company company1 = new Company() { Expense = 200, Salary = 1000, Year = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") };
Company company2 = new Company() { Expense = 300, Salary = 800, Year = new DateTime(2014, 2, 1).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") };
Company company3 = new Company() { Expense = 500, Salary = 1400, Year = new DateTime(2014, 3, 1).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") };

ListCompanies.Add(company1);
ListCompanies.Add(company2);
ListCompanies.Add(company3);

var Exp = ListCompanies.Where(e => ListCompanies.Contains(e.Expense));
```

This doesn't work as I'm getting this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'Project1.Company

I know I could get the direct values out of a LINQ query like this:

```
var CompanyName = ListCompanies.Where(cn => cn.Name.Contains("X"));
```

which would give me all company names that contains "X". Isn't it possible to get all company names in `ListConpanies`?

Hope I'm not to unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you asking about...? " I would like to return all salaries from the list using LINQ.", then you ask "Isn't it possible to get all company names in ListConpanies?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all salaries into a separate list with a `Select`:

```
var allSalaries = ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Salary).ToList();
```

This produces a list wit `{1000, 800, 1400}`

If you do not want a list, but wish to iterate over a particular attribute from your list, you can do a `Select` in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var expense in ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Expense)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice!, didn't know i could use the LINQ query like that as argument in a foreach. Great tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get all salaries, try this:

```
var salaries = ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Salary);
```

This will get you an `IEnumerable`. If desired, you can convert it using `ToArray()`, `ToList()`etc.

Comment: Simple and straight forward. Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all salaries, simply use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var salaries = ListCompanies.Select(e => e.Salary );
```

Also, you are not right when saying that:

```
var CompanyName = ListCompanies.Where(cn => cn.Name.Contains("X"));
```

would give you all company names that contains "X". It will return a `IEnumerable<Company>` of companies which name contains "X". It might not single but multiple companies. You can then select their salaries by combining `Where` and `Select` clauses:

```
var filteredSalaries = ListCompanies.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("X"))
                                    .Select(c => c.Salary);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are searching an int Expense in a collection of (Company type) companies so type difference causes the error.

You can select any property from a IEnumerable by using Select extenion Method and it will return IEnumerable.

```
 var Expenses = ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Expenses);
 var Salaries = ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Salary);
 var Years = ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Year);
```

These all Expenses, Salaries and Years are of IEnurable type. If you want list from this then you have to call ToList() extension method.

```
 var Expenses = ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Expenses).ToList();
 var Salaries = ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Salary).ToList();
 var Years = ListCompanies.Select(c => c.Year).ToList();
```

Comment: I see. Well this information is pretty fundamental. Thx for explaining!